# Issue with Chrome, tabindex and radio buttons

Tags: google-chrome, radio-button, tabindex

[It seems Chrome doesn't register tabindex on radio button](http://jsfiddle.net/y2pke/1/) by default.

If you click on one of the radio button then push *tab*, chrome will focus the *first link* in the page.
If you click on *another type of* input element, he will continue in the form, *as expected*.

[If you put tabindex everywhere](http://jsfiddle.net/y2pke/3/), the form will mostly work as expected, except if you select (*click on*) a radio button, then *tabbing* will select the **first** form element.

How could I reproduce the same experience as in IE/FF?

Comment: And this issue is further complicated if you use jQuery buttonsets on radio buttons..

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this issue too.  
I figured out that if you gave each radio button it's own 
 ~ name=unique
 ~ name=unique2
 ~ name=unique3 
that the tabindex would work.
Check out this website: 
[Form Trick: Set the Tabbing Order](http://www.boogiejack.com/form_trick2.html)
You can see how he has different name values for all the radio buttons.

Hope that helped,
Diana

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the [grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Defining_a_radio_group) functionality of radio buttons?